# How to replace strings containing 'greater than' and 'less than'

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to replace strings containing `>` and `<` with R

```
  datanames<-names(data)
  datanames
  ## [1] BbMx>2.5   BbAv>2.5    BbMx<2.5    BbAv<2.5
  datanames<-gsub("[>]","gt",datanames)
  datanames<-gsub("[<]","lt",datanames)
  datanames<-gsub("[.]","",datanames)
  datanames
  ## [1] BbMx25 BbAv25     BbMx251     BbAv251
```

What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: For some strange reason R doesn't read the same character of the csv. Namely in my csv I read with libreoffice

```
  "BbMx>2.5"  "BbAv>2.5"    "BbMx<2.5"    "BbAv<2.5"
```

but once R read csv turn this strings in

```
  "BbMx.2.5"   "BbAv.2.5"   "BbMx.2.5.1" "BbAv.2.5.1"
```

Comment: can't replicate.  `dput(datanames)` please?

Comment: I also get "BbMxgt25" "BbAvgt25" "BbMxlt25" "BbAvlt25" as output. It looks like you are getting factors somehow (because they don't have quotes around the character values). Is this really the exact code you are running?

Comment: For some strange reason R don't read the sames character of the csv. Namely in my csv I read `BbMx>2.5  BbAv>2.5    BbMx<2.5    BbAv<2.5` but once R read csv turn this strings in `"BbMx.2.5"   "BbAv.2.5"   "BbMx.2.5.1" "BbAv.2.5.1"`

Comment: @emanuele Yes. R has rules about valid column names in data.frames and most punctuation is excluded (except for periods) so it automatically cleans them upon import. You can disable that auto-renaming with `check.names=F` and then do the renaming yourself.

Comment: Thanx. This was the problem :)

Comment: @MrFlick (or OP, or someone): either post comment as an answer, or edit answer below to include the actual answer?

Comment: the lesson for the future, I think, is that the way to debug these kinds of problems is to inspect the interim results (or useful summaries of them, if they're large) and see exactly where results start to diverge from your expectations ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just do

```
x <- c("BbMx>2.5","BbAv>2.5","BbMx<2.5","BbAv<2.5")
x <- gsub("[>]","gt",x)
x <- gsub("[<]","lt",x)
x <- gsub("[.]","",x)
```

You should get

```
"BbMxgt25" "BbAvgt25" "BbMxlt25" "BbAvlt25"
```

as expected. The problem is that the input from `names(data)` isn't what you think it is.

R has rules about valid column names in data.frames. R will run `make.names` on those values to attempt to make uniuqe, valid names. This involved replacing non-alphanumeric values with periods and adding suffixes to ensure uniqueness.

To disable the auto-renaming, you can set `check.names=F` with the `read.table/read.csv` function and do the renaming yourself.

So if you have

```
x<-c("BbMx>2.5", "BbAv>2.5", "BbMx<2.5","BbAv<2.5" )
```

Then

```
make.names(x, unique=T)
# [1] "BbMx.2.5"   "BbAv.2.5"   "BbMx.2.5.1" "BbAv.2.5.1"
```

So ultimately this had nothing to do with `gsub`. This was really about how R transforms raw data into data.frames.

Answer (score 3):

I know [@MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) has provided an answer already, but just to comment on the way you are implementing your characters and calls using `gsub`, the `<` and `>` characters are not considered a character of special meaning so you do not need to place them inside a character class `[ ]`, you can use them as a literal.

And you can cascade your `gsub` functions together here.

```
datanames <- gsub('>', 'gt', gsub('<', 'lt', gsub('\\.', '', datanames)))
```