# Replace "<x" by "x"

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have strings like "<x" which must be changed to "x".

for example:

"<0.1" will be "0.1"

I tried this:

```
data2[1:nrow(data2),] <- as.data.frame(apply(data2[1:nrow(data2),], 2, function(x) sub("<a*", "", x)))
```

But it also changes strings like "wrong (<0.1)" to "wrong (0.1)". It has to only change the values like "<x" to "x".

I searched for examples like:
[String replace specific part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58650038/string-replace-specific-part-of-string)
[Replace $x<y$ by $x < y$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639028/replace-xy-by-x-y)

But they unfortunately did not help.

Comment: have a look to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983450/how-to-replace-strings-containing-greater-than-and-less-than]. Special characters need to be dealt specifically (sometimes escaped multiple times).

Comment: like this? `sub("^<a*", "", x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readr`'s `parse_number` function to extract the number from text directly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df <- data.frame(a = c('1', '>0.01', '<0.2'), b = c(1, 'wrong (<0.1)', '<0.05'))

df %>% mutate(across(.fns = parse_number))
#     a    b
#1 1.00 1.00
#2 0.01 0.10
#3 0.20 0.05
```

Comment: It works for <0.1 to 0.1, but how do you change "wrong (<0.1)" to "0.1"? 0.1 could be any number

Comment: But you said you don't want to change that? Using `dplyr` and `readr` try `df %>% mutate(across(.fns = parse_number))`

Comment: I said that it also changes "wrong (<0.1)" to "wrong (0.1)", which is not good because I only want the numbers. It only removed < and not all text except the numbers.

Comment: I tried this: `str_replace_all(x, "[wrong(<)]", "")` and worked also